# An element of $C(\mathbb{D})$ which is not in the connected component

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $\mathbb{\bar{D}}$ denote the closed unit disc in the complex plane. Let $A=C(\mathbb{\bar{D}})$ be the Banach algebra of all complex valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{\bar{D}}$. My Question is with regard to [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307156/regarding-exponential-in-a-banach-algebra). Let $G(A)$ denote the set of all invertible elements in $A$ and let $G_1(A)$ denote the connected component of $G(A)$ containing the identity element. Can you give an example of an element $f\in A$ such that $f\in G(A)\setminus G_1(A)$?

Comment: Do you really have such an element? In the linked MO post, the answer consider functions on the annulus, not the disc.

Comment: @ArcticChar  Yes. They gave an answer regarding the continuous functions over the Annulus. I want to know if such an example exists in the case of the closed unit disc? Or are the elements of $G(A)$ connected?

Comment: But all continuous functions $\overline D \to \mathbb C^*$ are homotopic to each other.

Comment: @ArcticChar I have not done a formal course in algebraic topology. Can you explain otherwise? Or direct me to some reference.

Comment: Arctic Char's argument is in fact just the convexity of $K=\overline{\mathbb D}$: For every invertible function $f:K\to \mathbb C$, the functions $f_t(z)=f((1-t)z)=f((1-t)z+t0)$ define a path from $f$ to the constant function $z\mapsto f(0)$.

Comment: @Jochen Hi Can you tell where have you used the fact that $f$ is invertible while defining the path $f_t$. I can only see it being used to say that $f(0)\neq 0$. But then we can say that any function with $f(0)\neq 0$ is path connected to the constant function 1.

Comment: You need that $f$ has no zeros to get a path of **invertible** functions.